# Update MySQL from CSV using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, performance, csv, jdbc

my problem is as follows:

1. The CSV file is downloaded at given intervals from server.
2. File has to be parsed (there are unnecessary spaces that have to be stripped).
3. Item price, rrp and stock quantity must be updated for each barcode.

Each CSV line contains article number, product title, warehouse id, warehouse name, price, rrp price, stock and barcode. The items table contains about 71000 rows. And barcode is not unique key in database (because item with same barcode can be in different warehouses). Issue is that it takes more than one hour to update on localhost MySQL server (about half hour to SQLite). Is there any way to optimize SQL query to make things faster? My current code looks like this:

```
    public void updateData (BufferedReader bufferedReader, Connection sqlConnection){
    String csvLine = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String sqlString = "UPDATE items SET price = ?, rrp = ?, stock = ? WHERE departmentid = ? AND barcode = ?";
    try {
        preparedStatement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
        while ((csvLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitLine = csvLine.split(";");
            preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(splitLine[4].trim()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
            preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(splitLine[5].trim()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(splitLine[6].trim()));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, splitLine[2].trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, splitLine[8].trim());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (IOException | SQLException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            sqlConnection.commit();
            preparedStatement.close();
            sqlConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So far fastest solution looks as suggested by @e4c5 with LOAD csv data to temporary table and using query:
`UPDATE items INNER JOIN temp_table ON items.barcode = temp_table.barcode SET items.rrp = temp_table.rrp, items.price = temp_table.price, items.stock = temp_table.stock WHERE items.barcode = temp_table.barcode AND items.departmentid = temp_table.departmentid.` Any way to make this even faster?

Comment: Have you profiled it to see which aspect takes the time?  Is it definitely `executeUpdate()`?  If so, do you have indexes on the tables?  (BTW, with those figures, it's taking 0.05 seconds per rec, which isn't too bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way in your case is to use Statement batching here is an example :

```
sqlConnection.setAutoCommit(false);//<<------------
try {
    preparedStatement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    while ((csvLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitLine = csvLine.split(";");
        preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(splitLine[4].trim()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
        preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(splitLine[5].trim()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(splitLine[6].trim()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, splitLine[2].trim());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, splitLine[8].trim());

        preparedStatement.addBatch();//<<-----------add a batch
    }

    //execute your multiple statement as one
    statement.executeBatch();//<<------------
    sqlConnection.commit();//<<--------------
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Like @Mick Mnemonic mention in comment :

> You could try if splitting into smaller batches of say 500 rows makes
>   any difference

So instead to execute your batch in one shot you can split your batch in small batches for example :

```
sqlConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    int nbrBatch = 500;
    int count = 0;
    preparedStatement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    while ((csvLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //Your code here
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        if (count % nbrBatch == 0) {
            statement.executeBatch();
        }
        count++;
    }
    //rest of your batch not executed
    statement.executeBatch();
    sqlConnection.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this made process about 15 minute shorter.

Comment: You could try if splitting into smaller batches of say 500 rows makes any difference.

Comment: yes this is correct @MickMnemonic it will be more quick if you splitting into smaller batches hope the maybe i can edit my answer with your comment, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, sure. I think I have normally seen batch sizes between a couple of hundred and a thousand.

Comment: @Sig check my edit, i think MickMnemonic mention a good point, you can use it for a better performance

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L, this cuts around 10 minutes.

Comment: @Sig if that help you don't forgot to accept the answer

Comment: After converting csv (trimming spaces etc, before using it) and then using batch size of 1000 i've got around 15 minutes total time for 70000 records, thats about reasonable. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much faster and much better way to import your data without a single line of Java code. That is with [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

note that LOAD DATA can do some amount of preprocessing for your CSV.  However it is not adequate in some situation. Then you would have to get help from java but java shouldn't be doing the insert.

Your java code should preprocess the CSV and produce another CSV which can be passed to LOAD DATA. 70000 records is  a breeze.

LOAD DATA does not support the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. But it does have the REPLACE syntax (which is slightly slower than duplicate key update, but it would still be at least an order of magnitude faster than what java or any other programming language can give you).

If doing an actually update is a matter of importance. LOAD DATA into a temporary table and then to

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM temp_table ON DUPLICATE KEY ....
```

Comment: Well but the problem is update, not insertion. Can you demonstrate how to use this for updating data?

Comment: It's a trivial task. See the 'REPLACE' keyword right at the top of the documentation.

Comment: `LOAD` into a temp table, then run a small number of SQL statements (no looping) to deal with dups and other processing that cannot be done inside the load statement, itself.

Comment: hello @RickJames been a while. Yes, that's a good suggestion as well.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work for me (or I do not get it right). Because my main aim is to update whats already in table (without adding new stuff from csv) and barcode is not a unique key (product can be in several departments) thats why I have "WHERE departmentid = ? AND barcode = ?" in my query.

Comment: Still load data is the right way to go. Load into a temp table and then do an update join. Your current approach just doesn't scale. Specialy if you don't have indexes

Comment: Ok, my table has the following columns: id|artnum|artname|departmentid|departmentname|price|rrp|stock|unit|barcode. ID is primary key, with autoincrement and unique. Temporary table has the same structure. And the query looks like this: UPDATE items INNER JOIN temp_table ON items.barcode = temp_table.barcode SET items.rrp = temp_table.rrp, items.price = temp_table.price, items.stock = temp_table.stock WHERE items.barcode = temp_table.barcode AND items.departmentid = temp_table.departmentid. Whole process takes about 25 - 30 minutes.

Comment: Did you notice how readable code in comments are. please update question