# Low performance writing to MySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, performance, server, inputstream

I have a performance problem with my server.

Now here is the setup:

I have rented a virtual server (4 GB, 2 vCores/Threads). On this server runs a Java program that connects to a second server via TCP. Once server 1 connects to server 2, server 2 starts sending data continuously (about 250,000 lines per Minute, each line about 50 bytes of data). Server 1 then splits each line and stores the data by adding a row to a table of a MySQL database also running on server 1. Ok, so here is the problem: In no way can my server 1 keep up.

These are the relevant Java parts.

Receiving data:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(bin, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
String line;

... something...

    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
        mySqlConn.WriteReferenceData(line);
    }
}
```

All just straight forward. And writing data:

```
public void WriteReferenceData(String line) {
    String[] data = line.split(";");
    String query = " insert into reference (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8)" 
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString (1, data[0]);
        preparedStmt.setString (2, data[1]);
        preparedStmt.setString (3, data[2]);
        preparedStmt.setString (4, data[3]);
        preparedStmt.setString (5, data[4]);
        preparedStmt.setString (6, data[5]);
        preparedStmt.setString (7, data[6]);
        preparedStmt.setString (8, data[7]);
        preparedStmt.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ... something...
    } 
}
```

So how could I improve the performance?

1.) Not at all, because the server is just too slow?

2.) Would using a different language, (e.g. without Interpreter) be helpful?

3.) Is it just sloppy programming?

Thanks for you help!
Raphael

Comment: So many factors can influence: connection pool absence, unclosed statements, single transaction for each statement and so on so on so on

Comment: i already answer a question similar you can check it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43778950/5558072 you can use batch statement instead

Comment: I agree; this is (almost) impossible to debug from remote; based on a single SO question. And keep in mind: this is a community where we help for free (well, reputation gain some of us). But if your commercial product has such a problem, you probably have to bite the bullet and hire some lone-gun-for-service who knows how to resolve such problems quickly.

Comment: Could server 1 store the data for processing later?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. @Andremoniy: If I omit writing to the database and just write out the data on the console then my server can keep up. So it comes down to the database operations. This is where I need help mostly.

Comment: @YCF_L: I will have a read when I come home, thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat: Your help is greatly appreciated. I am a private person not intending to sell the product.

Comment: Too bad; I thought about offering consulting-for-reputation-gains. But seriously: when there are simple answers, maybe you get them here. Meaning: if you really got some "basic thing wrong", somebody might be able to tell you. But if this is a more sophisticated problem, then chances arent that high that you will get it resolved here.

Comment: So 250.000 inserts per minute. How long it has been running? Usually the bigger the table, the slower the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it really came down to stopping inserting each row seperately.

However, simply using the Batch Statement as YCF_L pointed out was insufficient. I also needed to modify my connection parameters as well. Without "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" there was no performance gain.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" 
    + database + "?user=userXY&rewriteBatchedStatements=true");
```

Thank you Jan Khonski, as you answer would have worked, too. However, I am marking mine as correct as I would like to list several ways of doing it.

I ended up discarding Batch Statements and used delayed database updates by implicitly turning autocommit off.

One way of achieving this is to encapsulate a series of INSERT statements with START TRANSACTION; and COMMIT;

See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).
So far I have no results on which method runs best when the database grows bigger.

Comment: Turning autocommit off is nearly always right and most important for performance. Using prepared statements is a must here, too. Then `useServerPrepStmts=true`, batching and inserts with multiple values. There are also some dirty hacks as disabling integrity or dropping indexes to be rebuild later.

Comment: Yep, I'd prefer having several ways to solve a problem, so I could choose the most effective one! And thank you, maaartinus, for providing more details on how to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Create one SQL query which inserts multiple rows at the same time! Do it programmatically!!!

```
  insert into reference (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8)" 
    + " values (v00, v01, v02, v03, v04,v05, v06, v07),
     (v10, v11, v12, v13, v14,v15, v16, v17) ..."
```

Only make sure than SQL query length does not exceed maximum allowed * 65,536* (it can be different for different databases).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html
*A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a PreparedStatement object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.*

You create PreparedStatement object each time when a new line comes!!! Instead collect multiple lines and then make one insert statement!

Comment: The default limit for MySQL is over 1MB, perhaps 16MB (not 64KB).  Chunks of 100 to 1000 rows is optimal.  `COMMIT` after each chunk.