# Most efficient multithreading Database Insert in Java

Tags: java, database, performance, sqlite, jdbc

We have to read a lot of data from a HDD (~50GB) into our database, but our multithreading procedure is pretty slow (~2h for ~10GB), because of a Thread lock inside of `org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.reset[native]` (see thread sampler).

We read our data relatively fast and use our insert method to execute a prepared statement. But only if we collected like 500.000 datasets we commit all these statements to our database. Currently we use `JDBC` as Interface for our `sqlite` database.

Everything works fine so far, if you use one thread total. But if you want to use multiple threads you do not see much of a performance/speed increase, because only one thread can run at time, and not in parallel.
We already reuse our `preparedStatement` and all threads use one instance of our Database class to prevent file locks (there is one connection to the database).

Unfortunately we have no clue how to improve our insert method any further. Is anyone able to give us some tips/solutions or a way how to not use this NativeDB.reset method?
We do not have to use SQLite, but we would like to use Java.

[image: ThreadMonitor] (Threads are named 1,2,...,15)

[image: Thread Sampler]

[image: Resource Usage]

```
private String INSERT = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES (?);";

public void insert(String urlFromFile) {
  try {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, urlFromFile);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Updated insert method as suggested by @Andreas , but it is still throwing some Exceptions

```
public void insert(String urlFromFile) {
try {
  preparedStatement.setString(1, urlFromFile);
  preparedStatement.addBatch();
  ++callCounter;
  if (callCounter%500000 == 0 && callCounter>0){
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    commit();
    System.out.println("Exec");
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:121)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setString(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:421)
at UrlDatabase.insert(UrlDatabase.java:85)
```

Comment: I i remember well SQLite itself only allow one operation at a time anyway.

Comment: Are you also using a connection pool in addition to multi-threading? Or are you only connecting to the database with a single connection? You may improve your timings if you create a new connection to the database for each thread.

Comment: Use batching to improve performance. Inserting one row at a time is slow, because round-trips to the database is slow.

Comment: @litelite and do you remember an alternative database format which we could use best?

Comment: @Andreas we store all our inserts and then commit like 500k at once. Batching brings no major improvement :(

Comment: Did you drop your indices before the inserts?

Comment: @MattClark no we do not use a connection pool, because we tried to give each thread a own connection and then got File locked exceptions. Does using connection pools make a difference in this regard?

Comment: @k5_ no we still have a indices. I will try without and report in a minut

Comment: @k5_ sorry have to correct my self :D it works kind of faster, but still slow and NativeDB.reset() still seems to use most of the time, and all threads locked/in monitor state

Comment: the idea of @Andreas is good, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778755/update-mysql-from-csv-using-java/43778950#43778950 i already answer a question similar to this

Comment: @YCF_L We will give batching another shot, with our example provided. Thanks!

Comment: You're saying that batching, i.e. replacing `executeUpdate()` with `addBatch()`, followed by `executeBatch()` for every 1000+ calls to `addBatch()`, doesn't improve performance? I find that highly unlikely, unless your performance bottleneck is *majorly* in some other area, e.g. excessive number of indexes on the table being inserted into. Commit interval has very little to with it.

Comment: I really, truly hope that code is just a really bad example, because printing a `SQLException` and then continuing execution as-if nothing happened, is generally a horrendous thing to do
.

Comment: @Andreas As I said I will try your suggestion out and post the results here once I have done that. But I have to say thank you already for your and also all others fast responses!

Comment: @Andreas yeah this Exception handling was just a real quick example to check whether our idea kind of work ^^

Comment: @Andreas Tried to use your suggestion but I immediately get some NullPointer Except: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:121)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setString(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:421)
 at UrlDatabase.insert(UrlDatabase.java:85)` My insert method looks like this: (next edit)

Comment: Try smaller batches, e.g. 1000. You can do commit every 500000, if you want, but batches are built up in memory, so keep them smaller. And remember to execute the last batch.

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately trying smaller batches doesn´t work in our implementation without extremly slowing down our threads.

Comment: I don't follow you. You were doing single non-batched inserts, effectively a batch size of 1. How can reducing batch size of 500000 to 1000 be *worse* than batch size of 1? Please note, when I talk about batch size, it's **only** about the number of `addBatch()` calls between calls to `executeBatch()`. It has **nothing** to do with how often you commit the changes. You can keep the `commit()` interval at 500000, as I already said in previous comment.

Comment: Yeah I got that difference between commit interval and batching, but the problem was the Exception, which came immediately after program start, even with an execution intervall less than 10. But I will keep this way in mind for our next project. So far we used a different approach, by copying all data at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases have some sort of bulk insert functionality, though there's no standard for it, AFAIK.

Postrgresql has COPY, and MySql has LOAD DATA, for instance.
I don't think that SQLite has this facility, though - it might be worth switching to a database that does.

Comment: Any recomendations? Can you use these kind of functionality with JDBC or in general in a programming language or only directly on a database server?

Comment: Looks like you can use Postgresql's COPY from jdbc - see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [has no write concurrency](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

The fastest way to load a large amount of data is to use a single thread (and a single transaction) to insert everything into the DB (and not to use WAL).